# Reduce memory cost with three matrices multiplication

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, memory, tensors

My program is eating up all my RAM and the operation is related to 3 matrices multiplication, as the code shown below.

example code:

```
{T, W, H} = {4, 10, 10}; (*crashed with larger values *)
matT = RandomReal[10, {T + 1, 2 T + 1}];
data = RandomReal[10, {W, H}];
matX = Table[RandomReal[i]*data, {i, 0, T}];
matX // Dimensions
matY = Table[RandomComplex[n+n I]*data, {n, -T, T}];
matY // Dimensions
Total[matX matT.matY]
```

After research I have detected the line of code which is killing a great deal of memory:

```
Total[matX matT.matY]
```

Where the dimension of `matX` is `{T+1,W,H}` , `matY`: `{2T+1,W,H}` and `matT: {T+1,2T+1}`, `T` is any integer but preferred even numbers.

edit:

one of the reason the RAM is being eaten up is due to the fact `matY` has imaginary part which is obtained from Fourier angular functions. The byte count is double size of real counterpart `matX` which only has real numbers.

This code works fine when  `{T,W,H}`are small. However,my goal is to calculate the case when `{T,W,H}={1000,1000,1000}`, but now I only half way to it.

I guess MMA is copying a lot of data in the RAM to do this `Total` calculation and I think it can be improved in terms of reducing RAM usage. I would really appreciate your helps to give me some ideas.

Comment: Where do the matrices `matX`, `matY`, and `matT` come from? Maybe that structure can be exploited. And what are the typical valued of `T`, `W`, and `H` that you want to use in practice?

Comment: thx for reply. I have added more clarifications, I have tried to minimize the structruce of those matrix such as using symmetry etc. But at least I known `{W,H }` cannot be any less while I can split `T` dimensions into many parts. It's only solution I have now. It's a bit of tedious but it works anyway.

Comment: Btw., I suspect you want ot use `RandomComplex[n + n I]` and not `RandomComplex[n + n i]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the actual data, everything else is derived from it:

```
{T, W, H} = {1000, 100, 100};
matT = RandomReal[10, {T + 1, 2 T + 1}];
data = RandomReal[10, {W, H}];
u = RandomReal[{0, 1}, T + 1];
v = Table[RandomComplex[n + n I], {n, -T, T}];
```

That is how you compute the result:

```
matX = TensorProduct[u, data];
matY = TensorProduct[v, data];
result = Total[matX matT.matY]; // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.67506, 512368624}

Here is how I would compute it:

```
result2 = u.matT.v data^2; // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming
Norm[result - result2, "Frobenius"]/Norm[result, "Frobenius"]
```

> {0.001187, 240432}

The relative error is small:

```
Norm[result - result2, "Frobenius"]/Norm[result, "Frobenius"]
```

> 7.58384*10^-15

Now it is up to you to think deeply and to figure out why this produces the correct result more than a thousand times faster and with the two thousandth part of memory. After that, you won't make that mistake again.

;)

Comment: thanks for this solution. I love it! But my challenge is how do I acquire `u` and `v` by given `matX` and `matY`, and `data` aren't same for each matrix. Is it possible to use "inverse" TensorProduct to get the `u` and `v`?  Because I assume main point of your idea is that do not explicit manipulate whole matrices in memory, so I guess obtaining `u` and `v` is the key to collapse the dimensions during computations.

Comment: Well, I deduced `u` and `v` from the way you built `matX` and `matY`. If you build them with`RandomReal[{0, 10}, {T + 1, W, H}]`, there is probably nothing that one can exploit... So, basically, what we exploit here is that  `Flatten/@matX` and `Flatten/@matY` have a [low rank decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation). Sometimes such decompositions can computed efficiently by exploiting how exactly these tensors are construct. For completely random tensors, I don't know of a better method than singular value decomposition, but that is much too expensive.